# How to write a XPath using the > Operators?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, operators

I am trying to add the item to the cart which price is `>` (Greater than) the $35 using the below XPath

```
//div[@class='m-product-mini']//span[contains(text()>'$35.00')]
```

but using this XPath I am unable to identify the price value, below is the HTML code.

```html
<div class="m-product-mini">
    
    <div data-id="EF_TLR04-1A-P_EF_TLR04-1A">
        <!-- main-image -->
        <div class="m-product-mini-image">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-quickview no-mobile" style="opacity: 0;">Quick view</a> 
                <a href="/bouquet/stunning-statement-bouquet/p_ef_tlr04-1a?skuId=EF_TLR04-1A&amp;zipMin=">
            </a>
        </div>
         
             <span class="m-product-mini-merchandising-icon">
                 <img src="new.jpg" alt="New Flower Arrangement by Florence's Flowers &amp; Gifts">
             </span>
          
        <a href="/bouquet/stunning-statement-bouquet/p_ef_tlr04-1a?skuId=EF_TLR04-1A&amp;zipMin=" class="m-category-flower-link centered text-large"><h2 class="m-category-flower-link-h2">Stunning Statement Bouquet</h2></a>
                 
        
        <a href="/bouquet/stunning-statement-bouquet/p_ef_tlr04-1a?skuId=EF_TLR04-1A&amp;zipMin=" class="m-product-mini-price "><span>$36.99</span> <span class="priceTag-discount"></span></a>
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below XPath to get required output:

```
//div[@class='m-product-mini']//span[number(substring-after(text(), '$')) > 35]
```

Note that you need to

- get rid of `"$"` sign, so `substring-after(text(), '$')` used
- convert result into integer, so `number()` is used

Comment: Thanks Now I am able to identify the Price

Comment: Need One more input how to skip the product when the 2 products price are same i.e in the product list there 10 products and out of 10, 2 are same price so using this xpath while adding to cart how to skip the duplicate(same price) product while adding to cart, please help me

Comment: I think you should use `findElements` and use a for loop... on them... what do you think?

Comment: @user3538483 , you might need to use Programming language features to filter items. Which Selenium binding you're using?

Comment: List<WebElement> priceSpans = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='m-product-mini']//a//span[(contains(text(),'$')) and not(contains(@class,'priceTag-discount'))]"));

   List<Double> priceOfProducts = new ArrayList<Double>();
   for (WebElement webElement : priceSpans) {
    String priceText = webElement.getText();
    if (priceText != null && priceText.length() > 0) {
     Double priceValue = Double.parseDouble(priceText.replace('$', ' ').trim());
     priceOfProducts.add(priceValue);
           System.out.println("The PLP Products Price are:"+ priceValue);
    }
   }

Comment: Using the above code to print the price and below is the out put                           
 The PLP Products Price are:69.99
The PLP Products Price are:64.99
The PLP Products Price are:59.99
The PLP Products Price are:54.99
The PLP Products Price are:49.99
The PLP Products Price are:59.99
The PLP Products Price are:39.99
The PLP Products Price are:79.99
The PLP Products Price are:119.99
The PLP Products Price are:69.99
The PLP Products Price are:79.99
The PLP Products Price are:119.99
The PLP Products Price are:69.99
The PLP Products Price are:119.99

Comment: so there are duplicate prices so how do I skip the duplicate one and how do I choose only one from the duplicate (i.e 2 products conatins the same price ex:59.99 )

Comment: @user3538483 , sorry, I know how to do this in Python, but I'm not so good in Java. Can you submit another question regarding this issue?

Comment: sure and Thanks for the help